# How to display matplotlib numpy.ndarray in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, numpy-ndarray

I want to display numpy.ndarray matplotlib in tkinter.

I tried in backend it works fine, but does not display in tkinter and show the canvas with graph empty.instead the code below display the picture in separate window as pop-up. How can I display it in the canvas and inside the window?

```
 from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import norm
import requests

from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials



from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


class Scr:

    def __init__(self, master):


        master.geometry('300x300+120+60')


        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_content.pack()


        tickers = ['AAPL']


        new_data = pd.DataFrame()

        for t in tickers :new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source ='yahoo', start = '2004-1-1')['Adj Close']

        lr = np.log(1+new_data.pct_change())
        var=lr.var()
        mean=lr.mean()


        drift = mean-(0.5 * var)
        stdv=lr.std()

        norm.ppf(0.95)
        x = np.random.rand(10,2)
        norm.ppf(x)
        Ze=norm.ppf(np.random.rand(10,2))

        t_intervals =1000
        iteration=10

        daily_returns=np.exp(drift.values + stdv.values * norm.ppf(np.random.rand(t_intervals,iteration)))

        S=new_data.iloc[-1]
        am = np.zeros_like(daily_returns)
        am[0] = S

        for t in range (1, t_intervals):
            am[t]=am[t-1] * daily_returns[t]


        graph3=ttk.Frame(master)
        graph3.pack()
        graph3.place(x=750,y=550)



        plt.plot(am)
        fig3 = matplotlib.pyplot.Figure(figsize=(6,6))

        canvas3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig3, graph3)
        canvas3.get_tk_widget().pack()
        ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(211)
        am.plot(kind='line', legend=True, ax=ax3).grid(linestyle = 'dashed') 



def main():

    root = Tk()
    scr = Scr(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

The error message I got is :

'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'

Comment: `numpy.narray` is not `pandas.DataFrame` which has `df.plot()`. Use `plt.plot(am)` `plt.show()` or convert `am` to `DataFrame`

Comment: `pack()` and `place()` are two different method to put widget in window - use one of them. You use `.place(x=750,y=550)` so plot is in window but widnow is too small and plot is not visible - `place()` doesn't resize window - so I have to resize window to see plot. `pack()` resizes window automatically and you would see it at once.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. The graph shows in canvas and the area around the graph is black and take too much space. Is there any way to remove the colour and make it transparent? I tried borderwidth and background colour but it does not work. Any sufesstions?

Answer (score 1):

`am` is `numpy.ndarray`

```
am = np.zeros_like(daily_returns)
```

and it doesn't have `am.plot()`.

But `pandas.DataFrame` has it. You have to convert `am` to `DataFrame`

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(am)
    df.plot(kind='line', legend=True, ax=ax3).grid(linestyle = 'dashed')
```

(and you can remove `plt.plot(am)`)

---

And remove `graph3.place(x=750,y=550)` which moves plot far away and it is invisible. You have to manually resize window to see plot.

---

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import norm
import requests

from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


class Scr:

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.geometry('300x300+120+60')

        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_content.pack()

        tickers = ['AAPL']

        new_data = pd.DataFrame()

        for t in tickers:
            new_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2004-1-1')['Adj Close']

        lr = np.log(1+new_data.pct_change())
        var = lr.var()
        mean = lr.mean()

        drift = mean-(0.5 * var)
        stdv = lr.std()

        norm.ppf(0.95)
        x = np.random.rand(10,2)
        norm.ppf(x)
        Ze = norm.ppf(np.random.rand(10,2))

        t_intervals =1000
        iteration = 10

        daily_returns = np.exp(drift.values + stdv.values * norm.ppf(np.random.rand(t_intervals,iteration)))

        am = np.zeros_like(daily_returns)
        am[0] = new_data.iloc[-1]

        for t in range (1, t_intervals):
            am[t]=am[t-1] * daily_returns[t]

        graph3 = ttk.Frame(master)
        graph3.pack()
        #graph3.place(x=750,y=550)

        fig3 = matplotlib.pyplot.Figure(figsize=(6,6))

        canvas3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig3, graph3)
        canvas3.get_tk_widget().pack()
        ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(211)

        df = pd.DataFrame(am)
        df.plot(kind='line', legend=True, ax=ax3).grid(linestyle = 'dashed') 

def main():
    root = Tk()
    scr = Scr(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```